# Modify content of response when using [Authorize]-attribute in dotnet core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

We're using the `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]`-attribute to authorize requests to our api. If the JWT is not present or invalid in the HTTP-Header, a 401-error is returned. We want to modify to response body to contain more information, rather than an empty body. We've tried doing the following thing:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
     var statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
     //write a custom body here       
 });
```

But the status code is always `HTTP.200` which seems to me a bit strange since Postman tells me that it is a `HTTP.401`

In case of an exception being thrown in our api, we have implemented a filter which implements `IActionFilter` to return a more detailed error message. This is what we are looking for to do in case of an `HTTP.401`. Is there any filter I can add to achieve this?

Comment: It is related with the order of your middleware. If your middleware runs before JWT middleware you will get 200 since it will be set after your middleware to 401 by jwt middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to add your own middleware before JWT, call the next handler, check the result and add your custom response.

```cs
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            var statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
        });
    app.UseAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that is curious on how I solved it:

I created a class that implements the `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
   public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
   {
       if(HasAuthorizationAttribute(context))
       {
          var isAuthorized = //Your authorization code
          if(!isAuthorized)
          {
              context.Result = new ObjectResult(..some object to return in response body..)
              {
                        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized
              };
          }
       }
   }

    private bool HasAuthorizationAttribute(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        return controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.HasAttribute<ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute>();
    }
}
```

This filter is registered in `Startup.cs` method `ConfigureServices` like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options => 
     {
         options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter));
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is this ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute?

Comment: It is a custom attribute that I made to decorate my api-controllers and methods

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`app.UseStatusCodePages()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepages) instead:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
        {
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            //write a custom body here       
            //for example
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                "Status code page, status code: " +
                statusCode);
        });
```